# How to rout the URL in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-routing

I have a page in my asp.net application, using this page with an number of links to open it, now I have a new version of same page with different name and extra functionality.

I need both page should be serve by same links depend upon user permission, suppose user "A" have permission to access old version of page then he should get old one and if user "B" has permission to access newer version of page then he should get new page, the page access permission logic will be derived from database.

I have an idea to do it by using a common page that will be linked with every link in application, under that common page I can check which page access current user has and redirect him accordingly, but I do not want to change every link in my application to change the old page link with common page.

I need some concrete functionality of asp.net application like URL routing.

Please help if any one have any Idea on this.

Comment: Those are different projects, right?

Comment: @JanesAbouChleih both pages are in same application.

Comment: `return View("Name",Model);` is what you're looking for, I guess.

Comment: @JanesAbouChleih, I am not using MVC My application is in pure ASP.net with web forms

Answer (score 0):

On the Page_Load of your login page, you'll want to check if the user is authenticated, and if they are to redirect them to your access denied page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!User.IsInRole("A"))
    {
           Response.Redirect("~/NewPage.aspx");
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not using MVC My application is in pure ASP.net  with web forms

Comment: thanks @Kristof, this can be one of the way to redirect, I too had thought about it,  but it has overhead to initialising the old page and then from old page to new screen, I can go with this approach but I am keeping it at last option when there is no concrete solution.

Comment: I got this link but this is not that I am looking for  http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dhananjaycoder/step-by-step-walk-through-on-url-routing-in-Asp-Net-4-0/

Comment: Is it the "default" page of your application wich the user has to see after a successfull login? Or he can get there through numerous ways?

Comment: yes, there are n number of ways in application from he can access the link.

Comment: In that case i think you can only achieve this in the pageLoad